# How to install PHP7.0 ssh2 in ubutntu 14.04 for PHP 7.0.19-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+2

Tags: 14.04, ssh, php, php7

Tried several techniques given at Stack Overflow and Ask Ubuntu to install ssh2 extension for php but nothing seems to work.
Also followed the tutorial at http://php.net/manual/en/ssh2.setup.php but doesn't seems to work.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you installed your **PHP**? with a package manager or compiled from source?

Comment: Did you followed these steps? http://php.net/manual/en/ssh2.installation.php#109853

Comment: @GhasemPahlavan those steps are for centOS.

Comment: no, It just compiles `libssh2` and `php-ssh2` from source and adds the shared object library to PHP extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solved the issue.

The method to install SSH2 for php 7 and 7.1 running on ubuntu 14.04 is below:

1. Installing the library

For PHP 7:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-ssh2
```

For PHP 7.1:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-ssh2
```

2. Restart Apache2 server

sudo service apache2 restart